# $(this).data('complete', booleanVarHere); returns undefined right after setting it?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn how to write a basic typewriter effect with jQuery.  Below is my progress thus far.  I got it to work, but it would fire more than once.  In my attempt to prevent that I ran into an issue beginning on line 35 - immediately after setting the data on the element, I try to read that data property and return it to console, but returns undefined.

```
var typeWriter = function(theELements) {

    // Convert elements you want to type into object of string values.
    function activateTypingForEachContainer($whatToType) {
        // cache context.
        var $this = $(this);

        // If typeWritten once already then don't do it again, because that's just weird.
        var eDataComplete = ($this.data('complete') !== undefined) ? $this.data('complete') : false;
            console.log('eDataComplete:' +eDataComplete);
            $(this).data('complete', eDataComplete);
            console.log($this.data('complete'));
        if (eDataComplete === true) {
                console.log('This elements typing has already completed!');
                console.log(isActive);
                console.log($this.data('complete'));
                console.log('---------------------------------------------------');
            return false;
        } else if (eDataComplete == false){
                console.log('Let the typing party begin!');
                console.log($(this).data('complete'));

            // cache text.
            var message = $this.text();
                $this.data('text', message);

            // Do not interrupt or restart while typing.
            // If active then stay the same, if not active change state to 'active'.
            var eDataisActive = ($this.data('isActive') !== undefined) ? $this.data('isActive') : true;
                console.log('currentElement.isActive:' + eDataisActive);
                $this.data('isActive', eDataisActive);
                console.log($this.data('isActive'));
                console.log('---------------------------------------------------');
            // If the typing isn't active for the current element then go for it!  Our mysterious narrator is clearly an extraordinary multitasker!
            if (!eDataisActive) {
                $this.css('color','#fff');
                typeIt($this, message, 0, isActive);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="assets/js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="journal">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
<div class="journal>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
<div class="journal">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
<div class="journal>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail where you set `.data()` and immediately read it back.  By my count, line 35 is the very end of the `typeIt()` function so I don't see how you're reading the value "right" after that line.  Also, are you accounting for the asynchronous nature that you're running things with your `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Inside the function `activateTypingForEachContainer` can you `console.log(this);` to see what `this` is in that context? Because you're passing in `$whatToType` but not using it anywhere. I'm assuming you should change `$(this)` to `$whatToType`. You may not be setting the data to the correct element. Which would make it always `undefined`.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield You are correct, and your question was very helpful in showing me what I was doing wrong.  Please write this as the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function `activateTypingForEachContainer` can you `console.log(this);` to see what `this` is in that context? Because you're passing in `$whatToType` but not using it anywhere. I'm assuming you should change `$(this)` to `$whatToType`. You may not be setting the data to the correct element. Which would make it always `undefined`.